# Could divs in multiple posts be grouped in a separate page through a class or anything else?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have multiple pages in a wordpress site and each page contains some divs, however these divs may contain something in common with a div in another page. I am not wishing to make a dedicated page with a dedicated taxonomy for each div or manually repeat a div in more than a page as it would be tedious.

So if I want to group these divs scattered in multiple pages in a separate page based on a div class for example (you can advise if there could be something else to group the divs), is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You sure this is how you want to do it? If I'm understanding your need correctly, you'd probably be better suited by turning your divs into posts, or a custom post type, then using a shortcode to echo out the specific post you want on a page.

Comment: I understand that I can add each div in a post and echo out what I need, but this will simply turn the site into thousands of posts which would be a tedious process. That's why I asked if this could be done through something else like div classes for example.

Comment: I’ll answer, but I wanted to add this comment first. What you want is going to be horrible for your page performance and SEO. You’re basically going to require users to download two pages for every url they hit. You can’t - to my knowledge - build a query that will allow you to get just a piece of the content without significant work that will kill any benefits you might gain. You’ll be loading the same ton of content that you will ultimately hide most of on every page and this will throw duplicate content errors and hidden content errors with Google and Bing.

Comment: It seems to be much more complicated than I thought. Actually I am a beginner in programming and I thought it may have an easier solution. If this is the case then I think I would go for the div per post solution as it seems to be the only reasonable solution. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Glad I could talk you out of this. :) Best of luck!